# file delete and rename issues

Tags: java, file, file-rename

Here is the code iam using for deleting file f1 and renaming a file f2 to f1..But it returns false.

```
String strLine; 
        File f1 =new File("C:\\Equinox\\RootSipResource\\root\\root.properties");
        File f2 =new File("C:\\Equinox\\RootSipResource\\root\\root1.properties");
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f1);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin,"UTF-8")); 
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(f2), "UTF-8");
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {         
            strLine = strLine.replace("root.label.43.2=PBS Kids"," root.label.43.2=PBS Kids NEW"); 
            out.write(strLine);
            out.write("\n");
            }       
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        br.close(); 
        //fin.close();
        boolean delete= f1.delete();
        boolean rename=f2.renameTo(f1);

        System.out.println("delete----"+delete+ "rename-----"+rename);
```

Comment: I suspect it is because you are printing the wrong value! you should print `delete` and not `f1.delete()`, same for `rename`, note that this ops have side effects!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename operation is [platform dependent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29), it may or may not succeed, no guarantee.

One reason why this is not able to rename may be because there is already a file with the name, which means delete didn't delete the file, which you say isnt the case.

Before `f2.renameTo(f1)` can you add `f1.exists()` and see what it returns true or false ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you rename twice ?

Should'nt be

```
System.out.println("delete----"+delete+ "rename-----"+rename);
```